# how to show all files of server using jfilechooser in java?

Tags: java, ftp, jfilechooser

I want show all files of server using jfilechooser and choose any file then download that. 
But i don't know that, is it possible? Please give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy but I think it's possible. You need to set a custom FileSystemView `JFileChooser.setFileSystemView`. Try to use google search (filesystemview ftp). Probably you can find implementation of FileSystemView which supports FTP.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `FileNameExtensionFilter`. Using it you can add extensions for selection.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpg", "gif");
chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
```

Comment: How it can help to navigate to a FTP folder?

Comment: Thanks @Java Learner. But i want show all files of server, not client.

Comment: You need to create custom navigator which will navigate through your server folder, show list of files in that folder as a link and write a  program which will download that file at client location. Yoy can make use of Sergiy Medvynskyy's suggestion which will give Home directory path like this - JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileSystemView view = chooser.getFileSystemView();
    System.out.println("The home directory is " + view.getHomeDirectory());